# ¿Como contar la cantidad de hijos (en realidad descendientes) de cada nodo en un árbol (estructura jerárquica)?

Tags: php, recursión

Cada nodo del árbol tiene un padre, excepto el nodo raíz (el nodo raíz es el primer nodo del árbol), y n (siendo n un entero >= 0) hijos directos (en el siguiente nivel). Yo no quiero conocer la cantidad de hijos directos, sino el total de descendientes de cada nodo.

Datos (ejemplo):

| Nodo | Padre |
| --- | --- |
| '1-A' | NULL |
| '2-A' | '1-A' |
| '3-A' | '1-A' |
| '4-A' | '2-A' |
| '5-A' | '2-A' |
| '6-A' | '3-A' |
| '7-A' | '3-A' |
| '9-A' | '6-A' |
| '10-A' | '7-A' |
| '8-A' | '7-A' |
| '11-A' | '10-A' |

Estructura de arreglo $nodos (La llave es el identificador del nodo y el valor el padre del nodo).

```
$nodos = array ( '1-A' => NULL, '2-A' => '1-A', '3-A' => '1-A', '4-A' => '2-A', '5-A' => '2-A', '6-A' => '3-A', '7-A' => '3-A', '9-A' => '6-A', '10-A' => '7-A', '8-A' => '7-A', '11-A' => '10-A', );
```

Estructura del árbol de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementé la respuesta utilizando dos funciones recursivas:

- contarNodosHijos: busca hacia adelante en el árbol (y por cada nodo incrementa en uno la cantidad de descendientes del padre en el resultado).
- sumarUnoATodosLosAntecesores: busca hacía atrás en el árbol, e incrementa en uno la cantidad de descendientes de todos los ancestros del nodo actual.

Código:

```
<?php

/**
 * Cuenta el total de nodos descendientes de cada nodo.
 *
 * @param array(idNodo => idNodoPadre) $nodos
 * @param string $nodoActual
 * @param array(idNodo => totalDescendientes) $resultado
 */
function contarNodosHijos($nodos, $nodoActual, &$resultado) {
    foreach($nodos as $nodo => $padre) {
        if($nodoActual == $padre) {
            $resultado[$padre]++;
            contarNodosHijos($nodos, $nodo, $resultado);
            sumarUnoATodosLosAntecesores($nodos, $padre, $resultado);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Incrementa en uno el resultado de cada antecesor del nodo actual.
 *
 * @param array(idNodo => idNodoPadre) $nodos
 * @param string $nodoActual
 * @param array(idNodo => totalDescendientes) $resultado
 */
function sumarUnoATodosLosAntecesores($nodos, $nodoActual, &$resultado) {
    foreach($nodos as $nodo => $padre) {
        if($nodoActual == $nodo) {
            if(! is_null($padre)) {
                $resultado[$padre]++;
                sumarUnoATodosLosAntecesores($nodos, $padre, $resultado);
            }
        }
    }
}

$res = array_fill_keys(array_keys($nodos), 0);

//contarNodosHijos($nodosPadres, array_key_first($nodos), $res); //(PHP 7 >= 7.3.0, PHP 8)
contarNodosHijos($nodos, array_keys($nodos)[0], $res);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
$res = array ( '1-A' => 10, '2-A' => 2, '3-A' => 6, '4-A' => 0, '5-A' => 0, '6-A' => 1, '7-A' => 3, '9-A' => 0, '10-A' => 1, '8-A' => 0, '11-A' => 0, );
```

Cantidad de nodos descendiente de cada nodo:

| Nodo | Cantidad descendientes |
| --- | --- |
| '1-A' | 10 |
| '2-A' | 2 |
| '3-A' | 6 |
| '4-A' | 0 |
| '5-A' | 0 |
| '6-A' | 1 |
| '7-A' | 3 |
| '9-A' | 0 |
| '10-A' | 1 |
| '8-A' | 0 |
| '11-A' | 0 |